# Consultar los ultimos registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

alguien podria ayudarme con esta consulta tengo la siguiente diseño de base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta que me traiga la ultima inscripcion que se haga tengo estra consulta

```
WITH CTE AS(
select  p.CI, p.Nombre, p.ApellidoPaterno, p.ApellidoMaterno,c.Foto,ti.NombreTipoSuscripcion, d.NombreDisciplina,
i.CodInscripcion, Convert(Varchar(10),di.FechaVencimiento,103) AS FechaVencimiento,  Convert(Varchar(10),i.FechaInscripcion,103) AS FechaInscripcion,
p.CodPersona,p.Telefono,p.Sexo,c.Peso,Convert(Varchar(10),p.FechaNacimiento,103)as FechaNacimiento,c.Correo,d.CodDisciplina,Periodo,dc.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion,
c.EstadoCliente,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY di.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion ORDER BY i.CodInscripcion DESC) AS rn
from Persona p 
inner join Cliente c on c.CodCliente=p.CodPersona     
inner join Inscripcion i on i.CodCliente=c.CodCliente 
inner join DetalleInscripcion di on di.CodInscripcion=i.CodInscripcion
inner join DisciplinaTipoSuscripcion dc on dc.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion=di.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion  
inner join TipoSuscripcion ti on ti.CodTipoSuscripcion=dc.CodTipoSuscripcion   
inner join  Disciplina d on d.CodDisciplina=dc.CodDisciplina
where c.CodCliente=@CodCliente and di.EstadoDetalle='ACTIVO')
SELECT  CI,
Nombre,
ApellidoPaterno,
ApellidoMaterno,
Foto,
NombreTipoSuscripcion,
NombreDisciplina,
CodInscripcion,
FechaVencimiento,
FechaInscripcion,
CodPersona,
Telefono,
Sexo,
Peso,
FechaNacimiento,
Correo,CodDisciplina,
Periodo ,
CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion,
EstadoCliente
FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1;
```

y al ejecutar la consulta trae este resultado :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

siendo que deberia mostrarme solo el de registro trimestral ya que su fecha de vencimiento es mas alto que el de mensual.

Answer (score 1):

Si le agregas el `TOP` y le haces un `Order by` obtendrias el resultado.

```
WITH CTE AS(
select  p.CI, p.Nombre, p.ApellidoPaterno, p.ApellidoMaterno,c.Foto,ti.NombreTipoSuscripcion, d.NombreDisciplina,
i.CodInscripcion, Convert(Varchar(10),di.FechaVencimiento,103) AS FechaVencimiento,  Convert(Varchar(10),i.FechaInscripcion,103) AS FechaInscripcion,
p.CodPersona,p.Telefono,p.Sexo,c.Peso,Convert(Varchar(10),p.FechaNacimiento,103)as FechaNacimiento,c.Correo,d.CodDisciplina,Periodo,dc.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion,
c.EstadoCliente,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY di.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion ORDER BY i.CodInscripcion DESC) AS rn
from Persona p 
inner join Cliente c on c.CodCliente=p.CodPersona     
inner join Inscripcion i on i.CodCliente=c.CodCliente 
inner join DetalleInscripcion di on di.CodInscripcion=i.CodInscripcion
inner join DisciplinaTipoSuscripcion dc on dc.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion=di.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion  
inner join TipoSuscripcion ti on ti.CodTipoSuscripcion=dc.CodTipoSuscripcion   
inner join  Disciplina d on d.CodDisciplina=dc.CodDisciplina
where c.CodCliente=@CodCliente and di.EstadoDetalle='ACTIVO')
SELECT Top (1) CI,
Nombre,
ApellidoPaterno,
ApellidoMaterno,
Foto,
NombreTipoSuscripcion,
NombreDisciplina,
CodInscripcion,
FechaVencimiento,
FechaInscripcion,
CodPersona,
Telefono,
Sexo,
Peso,
FechaNacimiento,
Correo,CodDisciplina,
Periodo ,
CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion,
EstadoCliente
FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
order by CTE.FechaVencimiento desc
```

Comment: Es una opción válida, pero ¿qué pasa si dos suscripciones terminan en la misma fecha? En este caso si el trimestral y el mensual tuviesen la misma fecha. ¿Cuál devuelve? Dado que la respuesta es que no se puede predecir, creo que el código sería mejor, si después de order by cte.fechavencimiento desc la acompañases de algo que hiciese el order by determinista, como puede ser el cte.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion

Answer (score 0):

Creo que de entrada podrías ser mas especifico en los criterios de ordenamiento para determinar el registro mas reciente, en la tabla de inscripción tienes la fecha inscripción, sin embargo mencionas el vencimiento de Detalle inscripcion por lo que entiendo que el `ROW_NUMBER` debería ser

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY di.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion 
ORDER BY i.FechaInscripcion DESC, i.CodInscripcion DESC, di.FechaVencimiento DESC)`

Por otro lado considera que estas particionando por `di.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion`, así que en cada detalle que tengas de la inscripción los agrupara por ese campo sin importar Inscripción